# Spring Boot Hibernate Error: Detached Entity Passed to Persist - anyone know how to Solve It?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot application where I have two entities, User and Account. The Account entity has a many-to-one relationship with User. Here's the basic structure of the entities:

```
@Table(name = "accounts")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String currency;
    private Double balance = 0.00;
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

In my service class, I have a method to create an Account associated with a User. Here's the code snippet:

```
@Table(name = "users")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
}

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
//    List<Account> findByUser(User user);
}


    public void createAccount(User user, String currency) {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setCurrency(currency);
        account.setUser(user);

        accountRepository.save(account);
    }
```

However, when I run my application, I encounter the following error:

```
2023-10-10T21:44:06.549+02:00 ERROR 9340 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:777) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at pl.bartoszmech.BankApp.Application.main(Application.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: pl.bartoszmech.BankApp.model.User
```

I know this error is related to trying to persist a detached entity, but I'm not sure how to correctly associate the User with the Account and resolve this issue.

Can someone please guide me on how to fix this issue and ensure that the User entity is properly associated with the Account entity when saving it in Spring Boot with Hibernate? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use CommandLineRunner, you should annotate run method with @Transactional. From VN with love

Comment: I tried using the @Transactional annotation on the run method in CommandLineRunner, When I run the application with this annotation, The error message points to an issue that seems to be unrelated to the transaction. So I think it could be related to how my entities are managed or persisted

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question which is attached below. Here account entity has a unidirectional Many to one relationship with the User entity which according to me will work better the other way around, in the service class we are setting the user to account with setUser() but please make sure that the User you are setting is saved in the table by userRepository.save(user);

[How to fix detached entity passed to persist thrown by JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77297461/how-to-fix-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-thrown-by-jpa-and-hibernate/77297490#77297490)

Comment: Thank you, I think you right, and ya I can fixed the issue after that

In my service class, I was indeed trying to set the user to the account with account.setUser(user). However, I had not explicitly saved the user to the database before associating it with the account. This resulted in a "detached entity passed to persist" error.
To resolve this issue, I added userRepository.save(user) before creating the account, ensuring that the User entity is properly saved in the database and isn't in a detached state when associated with the Account entity.

Comment: Glad it helped you kelvin, can you please upvote my answer?

Comment: ya of course, thank you so much